# Assembler stuck in sys_read loop

Tags: loops, assembly, ascii, infinite-loop, system-calls

I've written a piece of code that takes a number in ASCII characters  from the prompt, converts it into a decimal number and stores it in 'dnumber'. The conversion has been checked and goes well. It goes wrong at the prompt. It seems to be stuck in an infinite loop while asking the user for the ASCII character number. I want the program stop asking for input when the user presses ENTER, but that termination value never seems to be reached even though I think I've set it that way.

I've asked two related questions on this forum lately and it showed that I don't understand system calls properly. I've read all the documentation on 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming', 'http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/' and some of 'http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf' and apparently I'm still not getting it. Hopefully you can show me the light.

Here is the compiler info:

```
nasm -f elf64 convinput.asm
 ld -s -o convinput convinput.o
```

Here is the prompt:

```
$ ./convinput
Enter a number and press enter: 
123

123
123
```

As you can see I've pressed ENTER twice, but the prompt still asks for input.

Here is the code:

```
section     .text

global _start

_start:

    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     edx, lenmsg1
    mov     ecx, msg1
    int     80h

    xor     eax, eax
    xor     ebx, ebx
    xor     edx, edx
    mov     esi, data
    call    input

    mov     esi, data
    movzx   ecx, byte [dignum]
    xor     ebx,ebx    ; clear ebx

    call    string_to_int

    mov     dword [dnumber], eax

    mov     eax, 1
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     80h

input:
    mov  eax, 3
    mov  ebx, 0
    mov  ecx, esi
    mov  edx, 1
    int  80h

    inc  byte [dignum]
    cmp  byte [esi], 13
    inc  esi
    jne  input
    ret

string_to_int:
  xor   ebx,ebx
  movzx eax, byte [esi]
  inc   esi
  sub   al,'0'    ; convert from ASCII to number4
  mov   ebx, 10
  mul   ebx
  add   ebx,eax   ; ebx = ebx*10 + eax  
  dec   byte [dignum]
  cmp   byte [dignum], 0
  jne   string_to_int
  mov   eax,ebx
  ret


section .bss

    dignum  resb 1
    data    resb 1000
    dnumber resd 1
section .data
    msg1 db 'Enter a number and press enter: ', 10, 0
    lenmsg1 equ $ -msg1

    ; ESI = pointer to the string to convert
    ; ECX = number of digits in the string (must be > 0)
    ; Output:
    ; EAX = integer valu
```

Comment: On linux, enter is line feed, ascii code `10`. Also, `inc esi` destroys the flags set by the `cmp`. PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks Jester! Where did you got that information from? I've been looking for a good reference/manual.  And yes I will, I will use a debugger. Changing code, and recompiling it takes ages. Thanks again

Comment: @Piepongwong any good instruction set reference will tell you what flags are affected by each instruction. Changing and compiling (assembling) code takes ages? Only if you're guessing as to how things work.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by values you put into eax you are using a 32-bit syscall table, which on linux is different than 64-bit one.

You can easily see what syscalls (and with what arguments) are called by running your program under strace.